# CDN (Akamai), origin app with RESTfull api and HTTP DELETE method "501 not supported"

Tags: angularjs, http, cdn, rackspace, akamai

AngularJS based app hosted on https://123.45.67.89 is accessed through a CDN (Akamai) network which manages the app's domain name https://www.killerapp.com. CDN network is configured to have cache TTL 1 day for everything /* except /api/* for which TTL = 0. The /api/* is the origin app's RESTful API which angularJS part calls with HTTP GET, POST and DELETE. GET and POST work fine but HTTP DELETE to www.killerapp.com/api/orders/00001 returns HTTP 501.

The question: is private CDN network supposed to block HTTP DELETE or there's a way to fix it with the CDN's setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE is blocked by default in akamai configurations, if you want to pass it through you should create a rule on your property manager (i'm assuming you are using property manager) and add the "Allow DELETE" behaviour to it,  you can check if it's already enabled by searching for this tag in the XML:

```
<security:allow-delete>on</security:allow-delete>
```

Piece of advice: DO NOT "allow delete" globally, create a specific rule and limit as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try the request using a curl statement from your terminal.  Add the akamai headers to it also so you can see where the 501 response is coming from.

Usually POST/DELETE/PUT requests are passed back to the origin from the Akamai edge servers so my suspicion is your app is returning the error response for some reason.  Looking at the response headers might help narrow it down.

Comment: by default POST/DELETE/PUT are blocked ok akamai configurations so you have to add rules to allow them